# How do I pass the contents of a textarea field to a java applet?

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea, applet

I have a simple HTML page with a large `textarea` form field and button. The page also contains an embedded Java applet. I'd like to pass the contents of the `textarea`  field to the applet when the button is clicked. Could someone show me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the head:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("myapplet").myJavaMethod(
      document.getElementById("mytextarea").value);
  }, false);
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<button id="mybutton">click me</button>
<applet id="myapplet" ...></applet>
```

`myJavaMethod` is the name of the function you want to call. Must be public and in the applets class.